# Android/PHP - JSONParser not working for getting web page content as JsonObject

Tags: php, android, json, httprequest

There are a lot of questions about JSONParser but nothing seems to work.
So, I have a php script on a server.

This php script gets some data from the database and generates a Json with this data.

I verified this Json and it is correct.

In android I have a JSONParser that connects to the php script url and gets the web page content.

The problem is that the page content is not correct and I do not know why.

I also used **OkHttp** and **URLConnection** and it gives me the same output.

I also used **RETROfit** and that does not work either, I have a question on stackoverflow for that.

It might be something related to JavaScript...

This is the **script link**:

[PHP script link](http://mobilehealth.byethost11.com/aScript.php)

This is the **json generated by the php script**:

```
    {
         "success": 0,
         "message": "RequiredFieldMissing"
    }
```

This is the **PHP script**:

```
<?php 
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
 if (isset($_POST['param1']) && isset($_POST['param2'])){

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/connect_to_db.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

 $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
 $param2 = $_POST['param2'];

 // get data
$result = mysql_query("SELECT param1 FROM tableName WHERE param2 = '$param2'") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if ($row["param1"] == $param1){
            // success
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Correct";
        } else {
                // no success
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Incorrect";
        }

    } else {
    // no data found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "NoData";

    }
    // echo JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
 } else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "RequiredFieldMissing";

    // echoing JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

This is the **JSONParser**:

```
    public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;

    static JSONObject jObj = null;

    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

This is the **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

This is the **AsyncTask class**:

```
public class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String param1;

    private final String param2;

    private String message;

    UserLoginTask(String param1, String param2) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
        message = StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... param) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "param1Value"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "param2Value"));

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(my_url, "GET", params);

        if (json == null) {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        } else {
            Log.d("JSON: ", json.toString());
        }

        try {
            if (json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS) == 1) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            } else {
                message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        } else {
            if ("Incorrect".equals(message)) {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_credentials));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            } else if ("NoData".equals(message)) {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_no_account_found));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.unknown_error));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is **the output** I get:

```html
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("6edf9232af73be55d6cc499e851409b9");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://mobilehealth.byethost11.com/aScript.php?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value&ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

**LOGCAT**:

```html
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**This is thrown here**:
jObj = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: try using xampp to run this request on localhost and I think the problem is in your free web hosting site.

Comment: it worked for a friend of mine, but I have no idea why it does not work for me. I will try to use another host or xampp

Comment: i have used postman to send request to your php file and i am getting the same result. Try sending a cookie less request.

Comment: It is giving the same result with or without cookies

Comment: What is charset you are using from php side. Is this same iso-8859-1

Comment: That might be a problem, but the main issue happens before that. I think it might be a problem with the host or the php script.

Comment: what error you are getting exactly...past your logcat

Comment: @Mikey, can you please share request ?

Comment: I just make a http request to http://mobilehealth.byethost11.com/aScript.php and expect success to be 0 and message to be RequiredFieldMissing

Comment: Things you must avoid to make  the class work for you: 1. make sure no space between your php tag e.g <?php //make sure no space here ?>. 2. make sure you disable error reporting 3. and make sure you are calling a correct function name from php class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what was the issue, but I tried on xampp and on a different host and now it works.
The problem I think was that the host was responding with a javascript somehow.
All the code above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to use UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1. I think this problem may be in charset which you are using.

and Make sure  some un-wanted characters were added when you compose the String(no special characters were accidentally inserted).

Comment: The problem the guy is facing, properly the guy is catching error from his php script and there is space between php tag